# Ajax - Set url for ajax from child View not depend on Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view inside a view, and I want to use ajax to pass parameters from view to controller, but the url of ajax always have url of parent:`http://localhost/Project/Detail/Project/DeleteTM/?input=3,124`

This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/Project/DeleteTM/', 
          type: 'GET', 
          data: {input:input}, 
          dataType: 'html', 
          success: function (result) { 
              if (result == 'true') {
                  UIkit.notify("Success", 
                  {status: 'success', pos: 'top-center' }); 
                   setTimeout(function () { 
                   location.reload(); }, 1000); 
              } else { 
          UIkit.notify("Fail", 
          { status: 'danger', pos: 'top-center' }); } } });
```

My parent view have url : `http://localhost/Project/Detail`
How can i change url of ajax when it send request to server!

Comment: Always use the `UrlHelper` methods to generate you url's - `url: '@Url.Action("DeleteTM", "Project")'`

Comment: I used this but in html code, i cant access ajax, i got that error:  `ReferenceError: deleteTM is not defined`
My link of a tag:    `<a class="modified-option" href="#" onclick="UIkit.modal.confirm('Are you sure?', function (){ deleteTM(@item.TM.Id)});">`

Comment: You have not shown any function named `deleteTM(). And stop polluting your markup with behavior (get rid of `onclick=..`) and learn to use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'Url.Content("~/Project/DeleteTM")', 
              type: 'GET', 
              data: {input:input}, 
              dataType: 'html', 
              success: function (result) { 
                  if (result == 'true') {
                      UIkit.notify("Success", 
                      {status: 'success', pos: 'top-center' }); 
                       setTimeout(function () { 
                       location.reload(); }, 1000); 
                  } else { 
              UIkit.notify("Fail", 
              { status: 'danger', pos: 'top-center' }); } } });
```